# How can I use keyword arguments when subclassing django's model FileField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to subclass Django's `models.FileField` but somewhere, the instantiation is going very wrong.

Here's my code:

```py
class DatafileObjectField(models.FileField):

    def __init__(self, source_key=None, **kwargs):
        print('SOURCE KEY IS:', source_key)
        source = settings.DATA_SOURCES[source_key]
        kwargs["storage"] = import_string(source["storage"])(**source["storage_settings"])
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MyModel(models.Model):

    # THIS IS THE ONLY REFERENCE IN MY ENTIRE CODEBASE TO THIS FIELD
    # Yet somehow the field is instantiated by django without the source_key argument
    file = DatafileObjectField(source_key='my-data-source', help_text="Upload a data file containing mast timeseries")
```

When I do:

```
python mange.py makemigrations
```

That print statement is issued twice:

```
SOURCE KEY IS: my-data-source
<output from checks>
SOURCE KEY IS: None
```

Followed by the inevitable error, because the second instantiation of the subclassed DatafileObjectField doesn't receive the `source_key` argument.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 142, in handle
    ProjectState.from_apps(apps),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 220, in from_apps
    model_state = ModelState.from_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 409, in from_model
    fields.append((name, field.clone()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 514, in clone
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/backend/datalake/models/mast_timeseries.py", line 52, in __init__
    source = settings.DATA_SOURCES[source_key]
KeyError: None
```

**What on earth is django doing? Why isn't `source_key` always passed?**

Answer (score 1):

A Model / model field needs to be serializable to be able to use it in the migrations system. Django uses the `deconstruct` method on classes to make them serializable. This method according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.deconstruct):

> Returns a 4-tuple with enough information to recreate the field:
>
> 1. The name of the field on the model.
> 2. The import path of the field (e.g. "django.db.models.IntegerField"). This should be the most portable
>    version, so less specific may be better.
> 3. A list of positional arguments.
> 4. A dict of keyword arguments.

Hence you need to override this method and pass your own kwarg to it so that the field can be serialized:

```
class DatafileObjectField(models.FileField):

    def __init__(self, source_key=None, **kwargs):
        print('SOURCE KEY IS:', source_key)
        source = settings.DATA_SOURCES[source_key]
        kwargs["storage"] = import_string(source["storage"])(**source["storage_settings"])
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs['source_key'] = get_source_key_from_storage(self.storage) # Somehow get source key here?
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

**Note**: I use some non-existent function `get_source_key_from_storage` since you haven't set it on the instance of the field. You can get the source key somehow or set it on the instance and use that here.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it by about 5 seconds! Thank you for your help @Abdul :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out. I'd seen the mention of the `deconstruct` method in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.deconstruct) but not fully absorbed its purpose.

Basically, the Field is instantiated (correctly, that's the first print output in the question) then its deconstruct method is used by `makemigrations` to determine *what pieces of information need to be saved in the migration*.

It tells the migration what's important to actually store.

So in my case I needed to **add** the `storage_key` kwarg into the values returned from the `deconstruct()` method (which meant saving it on the model).

In this particular use case, because I'm determining what storage class to use on instantiation, I *don't* also need to serialise the `storage` kwarg, so I delete that.

Working solution:

```py
class DatafileObjectField(models.FileField):

    def __init__(self, source_key=None, **kwargs):
        self.source_key = source_key
        source = settings.OCTUE_DATA_SOURCES[source_key]
        kwargs["storage"] = import_string(source["storage"])(**source["storage_settings"])
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        # Make sure the migration knows that this settings key is required for instantiation
        kwargs["source_key"] = self.source_key
        # Remove this key, which is no longer required (calculated during __init__)
        kwargs.pop("storage")
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```